# cuda-memcheck fails to detect memory leak in an R package

Tags: r, memory-leaks, cuda, valgrind

I'm building CUDA-accelerated R packages, and I want to debug with `cuda-memcheck`. So in [this minimal example](https://github.com/wlandau/rcppcuda/tree/deliberate_memory_leak) (in the `deliberate_memory_leak` GitHub branch), I create a memory leak in `someCUDAcode.c` by commenting out a necessary call to `cudaFree`. Then, I see if `cuda-memcheck` can find the leak.

```
$ cuda-memcheck --leak-check full  Rscript -e 'library(rcppcuda); hello()'
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
An object of class "MyClass"
Slot "x":
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

Slot "y":
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[1] "Object changed."
An object of class "MyClass"
Slot "x":
 [1] 500   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10

Slot "y":
 [1]    1 1000    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

========= LEAK SUMMARY: 0 bytes leaked in 0 allocations
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

No luck. Then I saw in the [R extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-valgrind) that `R -d "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full" --vanilla < mypkg-Ex.R` is the right way to use `valgrind`. So I created a `test.R` file with `library(rcppcuda); hello()` and tried this.

```
R -d "cuda-memcheck --leak-check full" --vanilla < test.R
*** Further command line arguments ('--vanilla ') disregarded
*** (maybe use 'run --vanilla ' from *inside* cuda-memcheck --leak-check full)

========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'
========= LEAK SUMMARY: 0 bytes leaked in 0 allocations
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

And finally,

```
$ cuda-memcheck --leak-check full R --vanilla < test.R
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK

R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) -- "Full of Ingredients"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(rcppcuda); hello()
An object of class "MyClass"
Slot "x":
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

Slot "y":
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[1] "Object changed."
An object of class "MyClass"
Slot "x":
 [1] 500   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10

Slot "y":
 [1]    1 1000    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

> 
========= LEAK SUMMARY: 0 bytes leaked in 0 allocations
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Is it possible to make `cuda-memcheck` work for R packages? I know I thought I had figured it out [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/cuda-memcheck-to-debug-CUDA-enabled-R-packages-td4691668.html#a4708479), but back then, I didn't actually verify the answers that `cuda-memcheck` was giving me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not valid CUDA code:

```
extern "C" void someCUDAcode() {
  int a;
  CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**) &a, sizeof(int)));
  mykernel<<<1, 1>>>(1);
//  CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(&a));
}
```

1. When we want to do a `cudaMalloc` operation, we use *pointers* in C, not ordinary variables, like this:

   ```
     int *a;
     CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**) &a, sizeof(int)));
   ```
2. When we want to free a previously allocated pointer, we pass just the pointer, not the address of it:

   ```
   CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(a));
   ```
3. Finally, the command line help for cuda-memcheck (`cuda-memcheck --help`) indicates:

   > --leak-check `<full|no>` [Default : no]
   >
   > Print leak information for CUDA allocations.
   >
   > NOTE: Program must end with cudaDeviceReset() for this to work.

(A similar note is in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#leak-checking) as well.)

I think item 3 is the key missing ingredient in your code.  The following modification to your code produces a proper report for me:

```
$ cat t786.cu
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUDA_CALL(x) {if((x) != cudaSuccess){ \
  printf("CUDA error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__); \
  printf("  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));}}

__global__ void mykernel(int a){
  int id = threadIdx.x;
  int b = a;
  b++;
  id++;
}

int main() {
  int *a;
  CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**) &a, sizeof(int)));
  mykernel<<<1, 1>>>(1);
//  CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(a));
  cudaDeviceReset();
}
$ nvcc -o t786 t786.cu
$ cuda-memcheck --leak-check full ./t786
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Leaked 4 bytes at 0x402500000
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at cudaMalloc time
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 (cuMemAlloc_v2 + 0x17f) [0x13629f]
=========     Host Frame:./t786 [0x2dbb3]
=========     Host Frame:./t786 [0x610b]
=========     Host Frame:./t786 [0x3deaf]
=========     Host Frame:./t786 [0x2646]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21d65]
=========     Host Frame:./t786 [0x2539]
=========
========= LEAK SUMMARY: 4 bytes leaked in 1 allocations
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: That `int a;` vs `int *a;` was just a typo. I understand pointers, I use them all the time, and I meant to put an asterisk there.

Comment: I think the `cudaDeviceReset()`; was helpful. Since I'm writing an R package, I don't have an `int main()` to put it in, but I snuck it in at the end of `someCUDAcode()`. Now, in the commit entitled "cudaDeviceReset in someCUDAcode.c makes cuda-memcheck work" in the `deliberate_memory_leak` branch, `cuda-memcheck --leak-check full R --vanilla < test.R` reports the leak. Thanks.

Comment: Be advised that `cudaDeviceReset()` eliminates a cuda context, which means the device has all of its code and data invalidated, and all (device) allocations are destroyed.  So you will want to be careful about where exactly you place it in your R project.  If there is a routine that your project would call on exit, that would be the place to put it, probably.

Comment: Good to know. It's easy enough to call it after I've already copied all the data I need back to the host, freed device memory, etc.